# Back button inside a TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to have a button inside a TextField which allows the user to go back to the previous page.

There are two different ways I figured this could be done:

- Either stack the button above the TextField
- Or place the button inside the TextField using prefixIcon

Sadly, I'm unable to implement either of these cases in a satisfactory manner.

The prefixIcon method:

- I get the desired button placement
- But, when the user clicks the button, the keyboard automatically pops up for a fraction of a second, and is then immediately dismissed.

```
TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      icon: Icon(
        IconData(58848,
            fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons',
            matchTextDirection: true),
        size: 30,
        color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(1.0),
      ),
    ),
    labelText: "Search",
    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    contentPadding:
        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 70.0, vertical: 10.0),
  ),
  controller: _searchTextController,
),
```

The Stack method:

- When the user clicks the back button, the keyboard doesn't pop up
- I am unable to align the button with the Text without visually approximating its placement (which compromises responsive design)

```
Stack(
  children: [
    TextField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Search",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 70.0, vertical: 10.0),
      ),
      controller: _searchTextController,
      // onChanged: (String val) => _filterWith(val),
    ),
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      icon: Icon(
        IconData(58848,
            fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons',
            matchTextDirection: true),
        size: 30,
        color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(1.0),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try switching the TextField to a CupertinoTextField? What happens then? (That is, if you're okay with this different one)

Comment: For second method, I used `AnimatedController` with `reverse` and `forward` to acheive It in my project. However, It tooks a bit works to correct the position and behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon my understanding of your needs it appears the stack method achieves the desired interaction but visually is not correct.  I suggest encasing your IconButton with a Positioned & Align widget like the following:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    TextField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Search",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 70.0, vertical: 10.0),
      ),
      controller: _searchTextController,
      // onChanged: (String val) => _filterWith(val),
    ),


    new Positioned ( child: new Align(
                       alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
                       child: 


    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      icon: Icon(
        IconData(58848,
            fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons',
            matchTextDirection: true),
        size: 30,
        color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(1.0),
      ),
    ) // IconButton


    ), // align
   ), // Positioned  

  ],
),
```

Perhaps a bit of tweaking with a Padding Widget might be required as well.  But you should be able to achieve your goal.